# How to solve this intent Error ?

Tags: android, android-intent

I Wrote the Following code :

```
package com.aamir.cool;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.facebook);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/exandrok?ref=tn_tnmn"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting error "Unknown Entity Intent" , "Unknown type of variable intent" .
How to Solve these Error ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your import statements:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
```

Comment: Raghav Still Getting 2 Error : " Unknown entity 'uri" and                        "Unknown member 'main of 'com.aamir.cool.R.id"

Comment: Try saving the file and cleaning the project from Build -> Clean in eclipse, or ant clean from the command line.

Comment: Raghav Still Getting 2 Error : " Unknown entity 'uri" and "Unknown member 'main of 'com.aamir.cool.R.id"

Comment: See my edit, and make sure you have an element by the ID of main in your XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Add the correct import statements

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri;
```

If you're using Eclipse, you can add/organise/optimise your imports with the following shortcut

`Cmd-shift-O` on OSX

`Ctrl+Shift+O` on Windows / Linux

> Rawkode Still Getting 2 Error : " Unknown entity 'uri" and "Unknown
>   member 'main of 'com.aamir.cool.R.id"

Please ensure that `main.xml` actually exists in your `layout` folder.

Comment: Rawkode Still Getting 2 Error : " Unknown entity 'uri" and "Unknown member 'main of 'com.aamir.cool.R.id"

Comment: Use the Organise Import shortcut I suggested to fix your URI entity problem. As for your R.id.main problem, please ensure you have mail.xml in your layout folder. I've updated my answer with the URI import.

Comment: Rawkode main.xml is in layout folder but still getting "Unknown member 'main of 'com.aamir.cool.R.id"

Answer (score 0):

After importing the android.content.Intent;  first check your xml files and be sure you dont have any layout problems and delete your R.java file and let it generate that again. after doing that right click to your project Android Projects -> Fix Project Properties then select "Project" and click "Clear" then try to run the code again. if still not working ctrl+a ctrl+x and ssave the file be sure you have no errors and ctrl+v again and try to run again.

Comment: try project -> properties -> Android and be sure one of them is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try verifying the AndriodManifest.xml in the main page which generates the package as seen in the gen/com folders